# Initialize child before parent - do not call parent contructor

Tags: matlab, inheritance, parent-child

In MatLab, i have a superclass A that takes some parameters, x and y

```
classdef A < handle
properties
   x;
   y;
   z;
end
methods
   function this = A(x, y)
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.initialize();
   end
   function initialize(this)
      this.z = this.x + this.y;
   end
end
end
```

The initialize method is supposed to do some initial calculations to fasten computation later.

Now i want to create a child class B of A, with it's own inialization, but B should be initialized before A.

```
classdef B < A
properties
   p
end
methods
   % B takes another parameter p
   function this = B(p)
      % Since B is a subclass of A, and A takes some parameters we have to 
      % call the constructer of A as the first thing.
      this = this@A([], []);
      this.p = p;
   end
   function initialize(this)
      this.x = this.p(1);
      this.y = this.p(2);
      % This is when initialize of A should be called.
   end
end
end
```

Basically i just want to initialize B before A, but because the constructer of the parent have to be called as the first thing, i cannot figure out how to do this.

In PHP I would do something like this

```
class A {
   public function __construct($x, $y) {
      $this->x = $x;
      $this->y = $y;
      $this->initialize();
   }
   public function initialize() {
      $this->z = $this->x + $this->y;
   }
}
class B extends A {
   public function __construct($p) {
      // Does not call the parent constructor.
      $this->p = $p;
      $this->initialize();
   }
   public function initialize() {
      $this->x = $this->p[0];
      $this->y = $this->p[1];
      parent::initialize(); // Now we are ready to initialize A
   }
}
```

Is there a smart way to design what i want in MatLab? Do i have to give up the inheritance of A in class B?

Comment: Some clarifications required: In `classdef B` at `initialize` what is `p` (and shouldn't we read `this.x = p(1)`, `this.y = p(2)`) ... and what is `X` property, should we care for the example ?

Comment: You're right. Edited the example.

Answer (score 2):

This goes against the principles of OOP. What you are trying to achieve basically rules out that `B` should be derived from `A`. From what I can tell, you really want to overload the constructor of `A`. Either do this using a `nargin` check in `A`, or if you really want to have a `B` for whatever reason, just use: `this = this@A(p(1), p(2);` in the constructor of `B` instead, to properly call the constructor of `A` (and get rid of the property `p`).

This is how you would simulate to *overload* the constructor by using `nargin`:

```
classdef A < handle
    properties
        x;
        y;
        z;
    end
    methods
        function this = A(x, y)
            if nargin==1 % 'p' was passed as 'x'
                this.x = x(1);
                this.y = x(2);
            else
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            end
            this.initialize();
        end

        function initialize(this)
            this.z = this.x + this.y;
        end
    end
end
```

This is how you would derive `B` from `A`, with a proper call of `A`'s constructor:

```
classdef B < A
    methods
        function this = B(p)
            this = this@A(p(1), p(2));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might go against good OOP, but I did not like my alternative. I will think about your suggestion however.

I was wondering about this in general, but in my specific case, A is a plane, given by a point and a normal vector, and B is a polygon given by a set of corner points. The normal vector of the plane is calculated in B. I think the inheritance makes sense.

Comment: I don't think the inheritance makes sense. A polygon is not a plane. They might have some similar code, but the concept of inheritance doesn't apply.

Comment: Well, okay :). But it lies in a plane.

Comment: @jborch: There's no doubt about *that*. ;-)

Comment: @jborch: BTW: For future questions it might be better to directly ask what you are trying to do. I think you oversimplified. Plane and polygon wouldn't have been more difficult to understand. On the contrary: The current problem doesn't describe your actual question at all. Better ask your actual question next time.

Comment: @jborch: Think of inheritance as: `B` should be able to do anything `A` can/have all the properties `A` has, plus what makes `B` special. You might want to have `A` as a property:
`planeThePolygonLiesIn` of `B`.

Comment: I fully agree with knedlsepp . As a side note for general case @jborch may be refereeing to: if it is true that superclasses constructors must be called before any reference to current derived class instance, there is no restriction about making "static" computations in derived constructor before to call superclasses. See [Make No Conditional Calls to Superclass Constructors](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html?refresh=true#brd2m9e-6).

Answer (score 2):

The complication arises since:

> If you create a subclass object, MATLAB® calls the superclass constructor to initialize the superclass part of the subclass object. By default, MATLAB calls the superclass constructor without arguments. [[src](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html)]

You can get around explicitly calling the superclass constructor by wrapping its work in an `if`-statement dependent on how many arguments it was passed ([`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)):

```
function this = A(x, y)
    if (nargin ~= 0)  % or (nargin == 2) in this case
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.initialize();
    end
end
```

And then `B`'s methods would look like:

```
function this = B(p)
    this.p = p;
    this.initialize();
end
function initialize(this)
    this.x = this.p(1);
    this.y = this.p(2);
    initialize@A(this);
end
```

---

It may just be error in the post, but `A`'s `initialize` method is referencing undefined variables `x` and `y` and not their properties.  It should be:

```
function initialize(this)
    this.z = this.x + this.y;
 end
```

Comment: What a terrible design from mathworks! Thanks for clarifying this.